# Regex for parsing directory and filename

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm trying to write a regex that will parse out the **directory and filename** of a fully qualified path using matching groups.

so...

```
/var/log/xyz/10032008.log
```

would recognize `group 1 to be "/var/log/xyz"` and `group 2 to be "10032008.log"`

Seems simple but I can't get the matching groups to work for the life of me.

NOTE:  As pointed out by some of the respondents this is probably not a good use of regular expressions.  Generally I'd prefer to use the file API of the language I was using.  What I'm actually trying to do is a little more complicated than this but would have been much more difficult to explain, so I chose a domain that everyone would be familiar with in order to most succinctly describe the root problem.

Comment: For windows, check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703223/17342313).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(.+)\/([^\/]+)$
```

EDIT: escaped the forward slash to prevent problems when copy/pasting the Regex

Comment: Don't you want to make that non-greedy (if this anon regex can handle that) so that it doesn't have to backtrack all that way to the slash?

Comment: This one assumes that there is a path and not just a filename.

Comment: It also runs into problems with current directory (.) and root directory (/).  The former isn't an issue (fully-qualified pathnames don't start with a dot); the latter might be.  The regex also does not handle .. back-traversals - that might be OK because fully-qualified might mean no dot-dot bits.

Comment: This also works... r'.*/(.*)$', group 0 will return the filename.  Since .* is greedy be default, it does all the work. Again assumes there is a path.

Comment: `^(.+)\/([^\/]+)$` The forward slashes must be escaped?

Comment: You need to escape the front slashes, but otherwise this answer was just what I needed when trying to solve this question on Answers.Splunk.com - https://answers.splunk.com/answers/777810/how-to-get-a-record-count-of-a-file-under-some-pat.html#answer-776884

Answer (score 31):

In languages that support regular expressions with [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
((?:[^/]*/)*)(.*)
```

I'll explain the gnarly regex by exploding it...

```
(
  (?:
    [^/]*
    /
  )
  *
)
(.*)
```

What the parts mean:

```
(  -- capture group 1 starts
  (?:  -- non-capturing group starts
    [^/]*  -- greedily match as many non-directory separators as possible
    /  -- match a single directory-separator character
  )  -- non-capturing group ends
  *  -- repeat the non-capturing group zero-or-more times
)  -- capture group 1 ends
(.*)  -- capture all remaining characters in group 2
```

### Example

To test the regular expression, I used the following Perl script...

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

sub test {
  my $str = shift;
  my $testname = shift;

  $str =~ m#((?:[^/]*/)*)(.*)#;

  print "$str -- $testname\n";
  print "  1: $1\n";
  print "  2: $2\n\n";
}

test('/var/log/xyz/10032008.log', 'absolute path');
test('var/log/xyz/10032008.log', 'relative path');
test('10032008.log', 'filename-only');
test('/10032008.log', 'file directly under root');
```

The output of the script...

```
/var/log/xyz/10032008.log -- absolute path
  1: /var/log/xyz/
  2: 10032008.log

var/log/xyz/10032008.log -- relative path
  1: var/log/xyz/
  2: 10032008.log

10032008.log -- filename-only
  1:
  2: 10032008.log

/10032008.log -- file directly under root
  1: /
  2: 10032008.log
```

Answer (score 12):

Most languages have path parsing functions that will give you this already. If you have the ability, I'd recommend using what comes to you for free out-of-the-box.

Assuming / is the path delimiter...

```
^(.*/)([^/]*)$
```

The first group will be whatever the directory/path info is, the second will be the filename. For example:

- **/foo/bar/baz.log**: "/foo/bar/" is the path, "baz.log" is the file
- **foo/bar.log**: "foo/" is the path, "bar.log" is the file
- **/foo/bar**: "/foo/" is the path, "bar" is the file
- **/foo/bar/**: "/foo/bar/" is the path and there is no file.

Answer (score 8):

What language? and why use regex for this simple task?

If you *must*:

```
^(.*)/([^/]*)$
```

gives you the two parts you wanted. You might need to quote the parentheses:

```
^\(.*\)/\([^/]*\)$
```

depending on your preferred language syntax.

But I suggest you just use your language's string search function that finds the last "/" character, and split the string on that index.

Comment: Many frameworks (e.g. .NET/Python) have methods for separating file names from paths without needing to manually search for the '/' character.  This is great because the tools are typically platform-independent.

Comment: Yes, but he hasn't specified language yet. If it was Python, I would suggest os.path.dirname and os.path.basename .

Answer (score 6):

## Reasoning:

I did a little research through trial and error method. Found out that all the values that are available in keyboard are eligible to be a file or directory except '/' in *nux machine.

I used touch command to create file for following characters and it created a file.

> *(Comma separated values below)* 
>   '!', '@', '#', '$', "'", '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', ' ', '"', '\', '-', ',', '[', ']', '{', '}', '`', '~', '>', '<', '=', '+', ';', ':', '|'

It failed only when I tried creating '/' (because it's root directory) and filename container `/` because it file separator.

And it changed the modified time of current dir `.` when I did `touch .`. However, file.log is possible.

And of course, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-` (hypen), `_` (underscore) should work.

## Outcome

So, by the above reasoning we know that a file name or directory name can contain anything except `/` forward slash. So, our regex will be derived by what will not be present in the file name/directory name.

```
/(?:(?P<dir>(?:[/]?)(?:[^\/]+/)+)(?P<filename>[^/]+))/
```

## Step by Step regexp creation process

### Pattern Explanation

#### Step-1: Start with matching `root` directory

A directory can start with `/` when it is absolute path and directory name when it's relative. Hence, look for `/` with zero or one occurrence.

```
/(?P<filepath>(?P<root>[/]?)(?P<rest_of_the_path>.+))/
```

[image]

#### Step-2: Try to find the first directory.

Next, a directory and its child is always separated by `/`. And a directory name can be anything except `/`. Let's match /var/ first then.

```
/(?P<filepath>(?P<first_directory>(?P<root>[/]?)[^\/]+/)(?P<rest_of_the_path>.+))/
```

[image]

#### Step-3: Get full directory path for the file

Next, let's match all directories

```
/(?P<filepath>(?P<dir>(?P<root>[/]?)(?P<single_dir>[^\/]+/)+)(?P<rest_of_the_path>.+))/
```

[image]

Here, single_dir is `yz/` because, first it matched `var/`, then it found next occurrence of same pattern i.e. `log/`, then it found the next occurrence of same pattern `yz/`. So, it showed the last occurrence of pattern.

#### Step-4: Match filename and clean up

Now, we know that we're never going to use the groups like single_dir, filepath, root. Hence let's clean that up.

Let's keep them as groups however don't capture those groups.

And rest_of_the_path is just the filename! So, rename it. And a file will not have `/` in its name, so it's better to keep `[^/]`

```
/(?:(?P<dir>(?:[/]?)(?:[^\/]+/)+)(?P<filename>[^/]+))/
```

This brings us to the final result. Of course, there are several other ways you can do it. I am just mentioning one of the ways here.

[image]

## Regex Rules used above are listed here

`^` means string starts with 
`(?P<dir>pattern)` means capture group by group name. We have two groups with group name `dir` and `file` 
`(?:pattern)` means don't consider this group or non-capturing group.
`?` means match zero or one.
`+` means match one or more
`[^\/]` means matches any char except forward slash (`/`)

`[/]?` means if it is absolute path then it can start with / otherwise it won't. So, match zero or one occurrence of `/`.

`[^\/]+/` means one or more characters which aren't forward slash (`/`) which is followed by a forward slash (`/`). This will match `var/` or `xyz/`. One directory at a time.

Comment: a file/directory name in most (if not all) filesystems that originated in a *nix environment accept all byte values except '/' and '\0'.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
[/]{0,1}([^/]+[/])*([^/]*)
```

Deterministic :

```
((/)|())([^/]+/)*([^/]*)
```

Strict :

```
^[/]{0,1}([^/]+[/])*([^/]*)$
^((/)|())([^/]+/)*([^/]*)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^(\/([^/]+\/)*)(.*)$/
```

It will leave the trailing slash on the path, though.

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer, but hope this will help

```
^(.+?)/([\w]+\.log)$
```

This uses lazy check for `/`, and I just modified the accepted answer

http://regex101.com/r/gV2xB7/1

Answer (score 0):

Given an example upload folder URL:

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14Q6d-KiwgTKE-qm5EOZvHeX86-Wf9Q5f?usp=sharing
```

The regular expression pattern is:

```
[-\w]{25,}
```

This pattern also works in Google Sheets as well as custom functions in Excel:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(N2,"[-\w]{25,}")
```

The result is: `14Q6d-KiwgTKE-qm5EOZvHeX86-Wf9Q5f`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, take more time to create clearer answers.