# Regular expression to match a valid absolute Windows directory containing spaces

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression to match a valid absolute Windows directory path, where directory names can contain spaces.

**Example matches:**

```
C:\pictures\holiday  (without trailing backslash)
C:\pictures\holiday\ (or with trailing backslash)
C:\ pictures\holiday
C:\ pictures\holiday\
C:\pictures \ holiday
C:\pictures \ holiday\
C:\pictures\ holiday \
```

**Example fails:**

```
\pictures\holiday (no relative path allowed)
C:\pictures*\holiday (not a valid directory path)
```

I have tried `^[a-zA-Z]:(\\\w+)*([\\])?$` but that does not match the spaces.

I have also tried `^[a-zA-Z]:(\s)*(\\\w+)*(\s)*([\\])?$` but that works erratically.

Regular expressions are my last resort. I have also tried to validate the text box using a non-regex solution, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory). But I have not found a method that works for spaces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to detect path traversal attacks? Are you expecting any dot symbols?

Comment: @Paddy Nothing so cool :) I'm developing an application where the user has to be able to specify a directory via a text box. I need the regex to validate that text box.

Maybe I should take path traversal attacks into account?

Comment: why it `C:\pictures@!#$1afaf\holiday` isn't a valid directory? I could be able to create a directory like that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You're right, I just checked and the only invalid Shift+number character for a directory is the asterisk. Editing my post.

Comment: Why isn't "C:\pictures\holiday\photo.jpg" a valid directory path? I can name a directory "photo.jpg". There's no difference in the accepted pattern for directories versus filenames because they're both "files", just with different attributes.

Comment: @BrianStephens Thanks, yes indeed that should be a valid directory path. Editing my post. My excuse is that it's Friday and after work for me :)

Comment: No threats if the user is specifying a location on his own machine. If the path data is not coming to your machine, why would you worry? If the user is specifying a file/folder location to be uploaded, the file reading part of your program will complain anyway. And the file-reader will handle more cases (like dots, network paths etc.)

Comment: Go home Terribad. Start on Monday :-). Finding reg-ex doesn't seem to be the last problem you'll face on this.

Comment: @Paddy I probably should, but part of me feels _this_ close to getting it!! Typical OCD programmer, I may be.

Comment: I know the feeling. We are this close to building a fusion reactor. For 50 years now.

Comment: I found a better solution to this problem that does not require regular expressions. The solution is to use an improved folder browser, namely the Windows 7 browser. 

Install the Windows 7 API Code Pack. In Visual Studio 2013 this can be done by going to `Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` and running the command `Install-Package Windows7APICodePack-Shell`. Then you will have access to `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog` which includes all the validation! SHAZAM!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a regex that will work:

`^[a-zA-Z]:\\(((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])\\)?)*$`

It makes the path conform to the NTFS standard (see the [MSDN spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I'll break it down:

`^[a-zA-Z]:\\` matches single drive letter, with colon and backslash

`(?![<>:"/\\|?*])` is a negative lookahead to ensure the next character is not invalid

`((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+` wraps that lookahead, followed by the next character, any number of times

`(?<![ .])\\` is a negative lookbehind to ensure the file/directory doesn't end with a space or period. Please note: Lookbehinds [are not fully implemented everywhere just yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent).

All of that is is repeated 0 to many times, with the last backslash optional.

For many [use cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) it may be best to restrict the path length to 256 characters. To do so, replace `*`with `{0,256}`.

**EDIT:** allow root directory

Comment: When I put that in a string literal, Visual Studio doesn't like it and marks it in red. Just to be sure the characters weren't altered during copy-paste, I typed that thing out by hand and it still flagged it as an error.

`Match match = Regex.Match(tbOutputFilePath.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]:\\(((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)*[^ ]\\)*((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)*[^ ]\\?$");`

Comment: you need to escape the double-quotes in the regex

Comment: Isn't a C# string literal supposed to do that automatically?

Comment: Ah, I think I'm supposed to escape the double quote with another double quote, even in a string literal, as suggested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal

Comment: I also modified my answer because I realized it allowed illegal characters before the backslash. The last character now has to match the lookahead AND a lookbehind that ensures it's not a space or period.

Comment: Alright, I escaped the double-quotes, and this is the resulting regex: 
`@"^[a-zA-Z]:\\(((?![<>:""/\\|?*]).)*[^ ]\\)*((?![<>:""/\\|?*]).)*[^ ]\\?$"` 

It doesn't match a directory containing spaces and having more than one level, and it doesn't match the root directory. For example, it doesn't match C:\ or C:\ pictures \ vacation \ (And I think it broke the comment box because I can't wrap those paths in gray background anymore!) xD

Comment: I fixed it to allow for the root directory, and I realized I didn't need the repeated pattern for the last level of the path. It intentionally doesn't match "C:\pictures \" because the spec says a file/directory can't end in a space or period.

Comment: Then it would be nice if Windows would prevent the user from creating directories that violate their specs, such as directories ending with spaces. :/ Thanks for all your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Following regex expression work for me for validate custom rules against a path-like string.

> /^[a-z]:(((\|/)[a-z0-9\s_@-^!#$%&+={}[]]+)+(\|/)?)$/i

```js
var path="C:\\backup\\newFolder" ; // valid
// var path="C:\\backup\\newFolder\\" ; // valid
// var path="C:\/backup\/newFolder\\" ; // valid
// var path="C:\\\backup\newFolder" ; // invalid
// var path="C:\backup//\newFolder" ; // invalid
// var path="C:\backup\new..Folder" ; // invalid


if((/^[a-z]:(((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+(\\|\/)?)$/i.test(path))) {
    alert("valid path string");
} else {
    alert("Invalid Path String");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isFileOrFolderPathValid(path)
{
    var result =  new RegExp(/^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i).test(path);

    if (result === true) return true;

    result = new RegExp(/^[a-z]:((\\|\/)[a-z0-9\s_@\-^!#$%&+={}\[\]]+)+$/i).test(path);    

    //result = /^[a-zA-Z]:\\(\w+\\)*\w*$/.test(path);

    return result;
}
```