# re.search() in python goes into an infinite loop

Tags: python, regex, text-mining, regular-language

I'm trying to extract file paths (Windows/Ubuntu, relative/absolute) from a text document.

The regular expression code below is used check if a word is a file path or not.

It works for most of the cases but fails for one case, where it goes into an infinite loop. Any explanation for this?

```
import re
path_regex = re.compile(r'^([\.]*)([/]+)(((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])(\\|/))?)*$' , re.I)
text = '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abcd-deploy-test-environment-oneccc/workspace/../workspace/abcd-deploy-test-environment.sh'
path_regex.search(text)
```

Comment: What makes you think it goes into an infinite loop? Most likely it just takes an awfully long time.

Comment: This is simply *catastrophic backtracking*: a regex cannot go into an infinite loop (if it is implemented properly).

Comment: Infinite loop detectors are tricky to write. Maybe the OP is just using a heuristic, equating "awfully long time" with "infinite loop".

Comment: You have a construct like `(.+)*` in there, which results in catastrophic backtracking. `^\.*/+([^<>:"/\\|?*]+($|(?<![ .])[\\/]))+$` should work.

Comment: `((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+` is almost the same as `[^<>:"/\\|?*]+`.

Comment: i don't understand much about re implementation. i picked up the regex from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702677/regular-expression-to-match-a-valid-absolute-windows-directory-containing-spaces) , the regex was for windows pathnames , i did a mod to use it for linux pathnames . why re module does not raise an exception or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there is a problem.
You have overlayed subexpressions mixed with spurious quantifiers.

***modified for required parts between slashes***
It is easily fixed using this `^([\.]*)([/]+)((?:[^<>:"/\\|?*.\r\n]|\.(?![\\/]))[\\/]?)*$`

The idea is to see just what your guarding against.
The guard is that you'd allow forward or back slash if not preceeded by a dot.

So, you have to include the *dot* in the exclusion class with the  \ and /
then qualify them in a separate alternation.

If you do it this way, it will always pass.

```
 ^ 
 ( [\.]* )                     # (1)
 ( [/]+ )                      # (2)
 (                             # (3 start)
      (?:                           # Group start (required between slashes)
           [^<>:"/\\|?*.\r\n]            # Any character, but exclude these
        |                              # or,
           \.                            # The dot, if not followed by forward or back slash
           (?! [\\/] )
      )                             # Group end
      [\\/]?                        # Optional forward or back shash
 )*                            # (3 end)
 $
```

Answer (score 2):

sln gave a good solution to your problem, so I'll try to explain *what the problem is*.

Welcome to the joys of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). The core of your problem is in `(((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+((?<![ .])(\\|/))?)*`. (Now that I've said that, all your problems are solved, right? Easy peasy.)

Assuming you're a bit like me and blinked blankly a couple of times the first time someone said "regex backtracking", we can work through your regex with the shorter input `/path./`. This is an invalid path according to your regex, but lets us (somewhat) easily walk through the problem.

`^([\.]*)([/]+)` matches the leading `/`. This works fine.

For the sake of readability here, I'm going to call the first half of the problematic capture group, `((?![<>:"/\\|?*]).)+`, `x+`, and the second half, `((?<![ .])(\\|/))?`, `y?`. The whole group is `(x+y?)`.

#### How is `(x+y?)*$` backtracking when matching `path./`?

1. `x+` matches `path.`
2. `y?` matches  (it matches 0 times, which is fine because of the `?`)
3. `(x+y?)` has now matched once
4. `(x+y?)` repeats, and fails, since it does not match `/`. Thus, `(x+y?)*` has matched `path.`
5. `$` fails, since it does not match `/`.
6. The regex engine backtracks:

   - `(x+y?)*` can only backtrack into its first iteration, since it only had one iteration.
   - Within that iteration, `y?` can't backtrack, since it matched 0 times.
   - `x+` backtracks, to match only `path` instead of `path.`
7. `x+` matches `path`
8. `y?` matches
9. `(x+y?)` has now matched once (`path`)
10. `(x+y?)` repeats and matches again:

    - `x+` matches `.`
    - `y?` matches
11. `(x+y?)` repeats, and fails since it does not match `/`. Thus, `(x+y?)*` has matched `path.`
12. `$` fails, since it does not match `/`.
13. The regex engine backtracks:

    - `(x+y?)*` can only backtrack into its first iteration, since in its second iteration `x+` matched only once and `y?` matched 0 times.
    - `y?` in the first iteration matched 0 times, so it can't backtrack
    - `x+` can backtrack to only matching `pat`
14. Hopefully you get the idea, but `(x+y?)` matches twice: `pat`, `h.`; then on the next backtrack we have `pat` `h` `.`, and then `pa` `th.`, and so on.

It takes 478 steps for the engine to determine that `/path./` is not matched by your regex. Every additional character in that problematic capture group increases the number of backtracks by a *lot*, and after a certain point your regex implementation is just going to throw up its hands and give up. sln's solution takes only 49 steps.

The behaviour of a regex engine when backtracking is difficult both to explain and to grasp, especially when limited to Markdown, so I would recommend running your regex through [a debugger](https://regex101.com/) to visualize what's going on.