# Use static string once in Regex while using two patterns with OR

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-alternation

Here is my regex:

```
STATICSTRING\s[a-zA-Z]:\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*$|STATICSTRING\s\w*
```

as you can see there are two patterns, `\s[a-zA-Z]:\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*$` and `\s\w*` which is combined with a `|` operator. and the `STATICSTRING` is repeated in each one.

Is there any way to write `STATICSTRING` once?

Comment: Use `|` and a grouping construct: `STATICSTRING\s(?:[a-zA-Z]:\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*$|\w*)`. However, `\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*` looks too suspicious. What should it match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please submit it as answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an `|` alternation operator in a grouping construct to group two subpatterns:

```
STATICSTRING\s(?:[a-zA-Z]:\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*$|\w*)
              ^^^                         ^   ^
```

However, the `\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*` part looks like a user error. It matches a `\`, then 1 or 0 occurrences of `\`, `|`, `*` or any non-whitespace char, and then `.*` matches any 0+ chars up to the end of the line. Make sure you fix it if you intended to match anything else. But `\w*` branch will always "win" as it always matches (either an empty string or a letter (and `[a-zA-Z]` also matches a letter)).  So, the pattern above is equal to `STATICSTRING\s\w*`.

Comment: the first part is a pattern for file path :)

Comment: @Nofuzy It is not important, the pattern you have needs a fix.

Comment: I do not know much about regex, I just copy and paste them from net with my needs. could you give the fixed one?

Comment: @Nofuzy No idea, I do not know what you really need.

Comment: my goal is to capture both `static c:\file\name.txt` or `static sdfsfdf`

Comment: To match anything, just use `.*`, there is no precise pattern for file paths. In Unix/Linux, file names can contain any character. For Windows file paths, you can use [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702677/regular-expression-to-match-a-valid-absolute-windows-directory-containing-spaces).

Comment: `\w*` with not capture for `:` or `\` characters

Comment: it is more than matching anything. because I'm replacing it with something else and there are several other parts in my whole string. If I match anything then replacing it, the whole string will destroyed :)

Comment: You cannot rely on `\S*`, but it seems the only work around for you. It will match 0+ non-whitespace chars. Something like `STATICSTRING\s+\S+`

Comment: just tell if `[a-zA-Z]:\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*$` suitable for matching file path in windows or not? :)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]:\\[\\\S|*\S]?.*$` = `[a-zA-Z]:\\\S.*$`, and it matches a letter, ``:\``, then any char other than whitespace and then any 0+ chars to the end of the line. No, it is not.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]:\\\S.*$` and mine will continue matching after the file extension too. it is the right match `C:\t.txt` but this one is wrong which currently is matched also `C:\t.txt ttt`. any advice or edit?

Comment: @Nofuzy There is no regex to match valid file paths.

Comment: I need to see only one `.` char and after that there should not exist a space char and only simple chars.

Comment: Well, try `[a-zA-Z]:(?:\\[^\/]+)*\\.*?\.\S+` or even `[a-zA-Z]:\\.*?\.\S+` but no one guarantees that it won't over-match in case there is a no-match and a match on a single line.

Comment: Works like a charm ;)