# Get a portion of string path

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

I have a file path as shown below.The last part (i.e. `video2.mp4`) is dynamically changed.I'm using `Javascript/Typescript`.

```
file:///data/user/0/com.sleep.app/files/sleep-videos/video2.mp4
```

**Question:** How to get the  `file:///data/user/0/com.sleep.app/files/sleep-videos/` part only from above string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var string = 'file:///data/user/0/com.sleep.app/files/sleep-videos/video2.mp4';


var stringPart = string.substring(0,string.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If only the filename changes try something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169021/7926064)

```
^(.+)/([^/]+)$
```

Try it at [regexr](http://regexr.com/3g68r). Your first group is the dirname, the second group the basename.

If you have further requirements/information (e.g. which tools you use), please refine your question.

Comment: I'm using `Javascript/Typescript`.

Comment: i updated my answer (since before it resembled basename behavior, now you get both). does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "file:///data/user/0/com.sleep.app/files/sleep-videos/video2.mp4";

url= url.split("/");
url.pop();
url = url.join("/");
```