# Regex to match a part of the path

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex to match the path of the file, excluding the file itself and drive.

```
c:\foo\bar\baz.txt
C:\FOO\BAR\BAZ.TXT
C:\FoO\BaR\BaZ.TxT
and so on.

Expression should match `foo\bar` (IN any CaSe).
```

The basic example I have is

```
\\.*\\
```

Another example is

```
\\.*(?=\\)
```

But I'm not sure I'm on the right way.

Live version is here: https://regexr.com/4kmu0

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: One option could be using a capturing group `^[^\\\r\n]*((?:\\[^\\\r\n]+)+)\\[^\\\r\n]+$`  https://regex101.com/r/ycCqYd/1

Comment: `^\w+:\\(.+)\\[^\\]*$` and get group 1?

Comment: @Sweeper Well, I need it for AutoHotkey. The live demo is here: https://regexr.com/4kmu0. In case it works in demo, it will work in AutoHotkey as well.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169008/regex-for-parsing-directory-and-filename since the solution is the same, but adding (or replacing with) backslash and adding the drive: group 1 of `^(?:.:\\)(.+)(?:/|\\)(?:[^/\\]+)$`

Comment: Well, both published answers (by _Vineet_ and _Michał Turczyn_) works - and I have upvoted them. However, the comments here by _Sweeper_ and _Grismar_ seems to work better. The version from _The fourth bird_ leaves the first slash. Probably I could remove it a bit later.

Comment: If you accept starting and ending with slashes, `/((?:\\\w+)+\\)/`

Comment: @johnc.j. You are right, I have added an answer with an updated pattern.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks. Yes, I see, you posted the answer with explanation. But the pattern itself is the same: `^[^\\\r\n]*((?:\\[^\\\r\n]+)+)\\[^\\\r\n]+$`. Isn'it?

Comment: @johnc.j. My bad, I posted the old one. Updated to the new pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the delimiter of the path should be a single backslash, you could use a capturing group and repeat matching `\` followed by matching 1+ times not `\`

```
^[^\\\r\n]*\\([^\\\r\n]+(?:\\[^\\\r\n]+)+)\\[^\\\r\n]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\\\r\n]*\\` Match not `\` or newline, then match `\`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\\\r\n]+` Match 1+ times not `\`
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\\[^\\\r\n]+` Match `\`, then 1+ times not `\` or newline
  - `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `\\[^\\\r\n]+` match `\`, then 1+ times not `\` or newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MTx08K/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[^\\]+\\(.+)\\`

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of a string

`[^\\]+` - match one or more chcaracters other than `\`

`(.+)` - match one or more of any charactes and store it in capturing group

`\\` - match `\` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzsuxY/1)

Answer (score 1):

**\([a-z].*)\**

> Above expression will match exactly `foo\bar` with Group 1.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. It is very short and simple, but there quite a lot very complex variations here. Nice, but suspicious. By the way, it should be slightly changed: at least, to the `\\\([aA-z].*)\\\`. Demo is here: https://regexr.com/4kn13

Comment: Are you sure? Try it with `c:\foo\bar\blah\blah\baz.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The following will do:

`:\\(\S*)\\ /gi`

This captures all non-whitespace characters which appear in between `:\` and the last `\`. The captured group then contains the required text.

Note the usage of `/i` flag for case-insensitivity.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tDMKVe/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?>[a-zA-Z]:\\)(.*)(?>\\.+\..+)
```

1. (?>[a-zA-Z]:\) : will match c:\ or d:\ ,this is non capturing group
2. (.*) will match anything in between
3. (?>\.+..+), this is again non-capturing group, match baz.txt or file.txt

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mErQpY/1)

Comment: `{1}` is always superfluous.

Comment: A non capture group is `(?:  )`, moreover why capturing that?