# Get file name from path via GROK or REGEX

Tags: regex, grok

How do I get application name from path in grok/ regex?

Example path:

```
C:\Temp\Logs\MyMainApp.SubApp.App.exe.010519.201123.9320.log
```

Expected Output:

```
MyMainApp.SubApp.App
```

**Note:**

- App name always ends in .exe
- Path may have more or less depth in terms of directories

Test:

```
^(.+?)/([\w]+\.exe)$
```

with `C:\Temp\Logs\MyMainApp.SubApp.App.exe.010519.201123.9320.log`

Also tried several options from [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169008/regex-for-parsing-directory-and-filename)

Answer (score 0):

For regex, this should work (might need some tweaking for your specific use case / environment).

```
^.*\\([^\\]+)\.exe\.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat as least as possible word characters separated by a dot until `.exe` after the last backslash.

The value is in capture group 1.

```
^.*\\(\w+(?:\.\w+)*?)\.exe[^\\\r\n]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^.*\\` Match until the last occurrence of `\`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\w+(?:\.\w+)*?` match 1+ word chars and repeat as least as possible matching `.` and 1+ word chars
- `)` close group 1
- `\.exe[^\\\r\n]*$` Match `.exe` followed by any char except `\` until the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z6rLIh/1)